# Unclear errors when trying to save data while overriding default 'create' method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Tried to write custom `create` method for my model, but run into some unclear errors.

Here is my code:

```py
# models.py:
class ItemModel(models.Model):
   item_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.item_id


class ItemVersion(models.Model):
   item_ver_id = models.CharField(max_length=13, primary_key=True)
   item_ver = models.TextField()
   config = models.TextField()
   model = models.ForeignKey(ItemModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
   session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
   finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def name(self):
      return self.model.name

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.model)
```

```py
# serializers.py:
class ItemModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   item_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^\d{3}-\d{9}$', allow_blank=False)
   name = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, allow_blank=False)

   class Meta:
      model = ItemModel
      fields = '__all__'


class ItemVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   item_ver_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^r\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)
   session_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^s\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)
   link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   config = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)
   item_ver = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)

   def get_name(self, obj):
      return obj.name()

   def get_link(self, obj):
      link = 'https://example.net/' + str(obj.model)
        + str('-dyn') + '/?iv_id=' + str(obj.item_ver_id)
        + '&sessid=' + str(obj.session_id)
      return link
```

```py
# views.py:
class ItemModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = ItemModel.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ItemModelSerializer
   lookup_field = 'item_id'


class ItemVersionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = ItemVersionSerializer
   lookup_field = 'item_ver_id'

   def get_queryset(self):
       pass

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       data = request.data
       model = ItemModel.objects.get(item_id=data["model"])
       item_version = ItemVersion.objects.create(
          # model=model,
          item_ver_id=data["item_ver_id"],
          config=data["config"],
          item_ver=data["item_ver"],
          session_id=data["session_id"]
          # finished=data["finished"]
       )
       item_version.model.add(model)
       finished = True if data["finished"] else False
       item_version.finished.add(finished)
       item_version.save()

       serializer = ItemVersionSerializer(item_version)
       return Response(data)
```

For some reason, I keep getting `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` and the `session_id=data["session_id"]` line is highlighted as the one where problem occurs nearby.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Edit: traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/core/views.py", line 47, in create
    session_id=data["session_id"]
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1332, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/aqv/workspace/django_rest_fw/ct_test/environ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: Can you post exact traceback?

Comment: Yes, just added to the post.

Comment: session_id is CharField() so the value should be in string as well. Also in the CharField(max_length=40, default=0) it should be default='0'

Comment: The `session_id` line is shown only because it is the last line in that block, its not necessarily the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only foreign key I see is `model` there, and in your code you aren't passing it.

```
def create():
   model = ItemModel.objects.get(item_id=data["model"])
   item_version = ItemVersion.objects.create(
      # model=model,
      ...
```

This will cause the FK constraint issue if you **do not** pass in a valid model instance or id because:

1. You have a `default=0` for the model field
2. But no `ItemModel` with pk=0 exists in the databsae

If you want `model` to be nullable, then you can just add that to the FK definition:

```
class ItemVersion(models.Model):
   ...
   model = models.ForeignKey(ItemModel, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Later on I see you have these 2 lines:

- `item_version.model.add()`
- `item_version.finished.add(finished)`.

These are both incorrect.  `add()` doesn't work on boolean model field, and the `.add()` for an FK is only valid for many-to-many FKs, which are not being used here.  The way you are passing them in the commented out sections is fine.

You can get a default value for the 'finished' flag by saying:

```
data.get('finished', False)

# this will throw a KeyError if "finished" isn't in the dict
True if data["finished"] else False

# this will not throw an error (but doesn't check the value of finished)
True if "finished" in data else False
```

Some other notes:

1) You use a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) without a Meta class inside.  Consider just using a standard serializer if you really want to do it by hand, or read up on ModelSerializers. If you use it correctly you shouldn't need a custom create method in the viewset.

2) `default=<anything>` is not a good idea on an FK. An FK should not generally have a default value (though there are some cases where its nice, like with pre-defined system data in constant tables)

3) You aren't using a serializer in your `create` method.  You are accessing request.data directly.  This will give you no validation, and no ability to say `finished=BooleanField(default=False)` and always get a value for `serializer.validated_data['finished']`.